# EF DataContractSerializer Exception

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, datacontractserializer

I've hit a very interesting exception while trying to serialize a graph of EF 4 STEs.

```
      System.IndexOutOfRangeException was caught
      Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
      Source=mscorlib
      StackTrace:
        Server stack trace: 
           at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectReferenceStack.EnsureSetAsIsReference(Object obj)
           at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.OnHandleIsReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, DataContract contract, Object obj)
           at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithoutXsiType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
           ...
           at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, Object graph)
           at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject(Stream stream, Object graph)
```

My serialization code is fairly simple:

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    DataContractSerializer dc = new DataContractSerializer(data.GetType());
    dc.WriteObject(memoryStream, data);

    memoryStream.Flush();

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
    var serializedObject = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

In my object graph, I've added a few child entities to a parent entity, and I've discovered that if I call the .AcceptChanges() extension method on the parent, everything serializes just fine.

Has anyone else encountered something like this? What could be causing it? Any ideas on how I can run down the culprit?

Update: I found a [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/wcf/thread/da5c8967-373a-4b0f-acbd-36f76a52de61) where someone else had a similar problem. They said that System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectReferenceStack.EnsureSetAsIsReference) is doing some cycle validation and could be finding a problem.

Update 2: I also found that setting preserveObjectReferences to true in the constructor for the DataContractSerializer clears up the exception.

Update 3: Ended up using approach described in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/03/26/561188.aspx) to call overloaded DataContractSerializer constructor with preserveObjectReferences set to true. This fixed the issue, although I still can't explain it...

So maybe now, my question becomes: **How is preserveObjectReferences on the DataContractSerializer different than having [DataContract(IsReference = true)] on all of the STE's?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems PreserveObjectReferences uses "non-standard XML constructs" for all your classes, while isReference is the standard SOAP way, but it needs to be declared on every class where it is needed. I had the same problem and it was because I had missed putting it on some classes. 
The common trap is that DataContractAttribute is not inherited, so you have to redeclare it (with IsReference=true) for each inherited class.